# find oldest line of code in git repository?

Tags: git

Is there any way to find the oldest line of code currently in the codebase? Out of curiosity, I'd like to be able to find the line or lines that have been unchanged for the longest time. I can imagine there is some way of running `git blame` on each file in the repository and processing each of them, but I was wondering if there is a simpler option.

Comment: I'd try a `git diff` against the very first checkin, and work my way upwards (I'd be very suprised if nothing survived). That can be get confused by files being renamed, lines copied from a file to another one, and so on.

Comment: The first commit(s) contain the oldest line(s). That's not what you want: you want the oldest *surviving* lines. But that's a hard problem: is a line that matches, today, a line in the first ever commit, but that was created anew without referring to that commit, the *same line?* Is the duplicate [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) the same ship as the original?

Comment: You'll need to define precisely what "oldest surviving line" really means. Blank lines generally survive forever, but are not useful metrics.

Comment: @torek yeah, I'd like to exclude blank lines. I wrote a short Ruby script for this and discovered that there are quite a few blank lines from the very first commit. So that's not as fun.

Answer (score -3):

You can use git blam that will tell you who and when single line updated in a file and you can easily find oldest update line
Here is command

git blame triple_welcome.rb

Comment: I'm talking about the oldest line in the entire repository, not just in a file.